# How could I make partitions of a newly created topic distributed evenly on all brokers？

Tags: apache-kafka, partition, broker

I set up a Kafka (0.8.1.1) cluster with 5 brokers. And then I created a topic with 16 partitions 2 replica factors on the Kafka cluster. I found that the 16 * 2 partitions distributed on only 3 brokers (11 on broker1, 10 on broker2 and 10 on broker3). How could I make them distributed on 5 brokers instead of 3 ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bin/kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh` as shown [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools) for automatic selection, or using `bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` where you can specify the replicas and leaders manually.